# Pandas importing tab separated data that also contains a json in each line

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have a tab separated datafile that also contains a json on each line and am having trouble reading it:

```
502     15      {\"p\":\"car\",\"rooms\":1,\"floors\":2,\"sf\":2000,\"br\":2,\"m\":0}
502     24      {\"p\":\"car\",\"rooms\":2,\"floors\":3,\"sf\":3000,\"br\":2,\"m\":0}
502     03      {\"p\":\"car\",\"rooms\":9,\"floors\":3,\"sf\":3000,\"br\":2,\"m\":0}
502     66      {\"p\":\"bik\",\"rooms\":9,\"floors\":2,\"sf\":3000,\"br\":2,\"m\":0}
502     28      {\"p\":\"bik\",\"rooms\":5,\"floors\":1,\"sf\":2300,\"br\":2,\"m\":0}
502     27      {\"p\":\"foo\",\"rooms\":5,\"floors\":3,\"sf\":1200,\"br\":2,\"m\":0}
```

I can do a csv read and specify the tab delineation, but then I end up with the json as a string in the pandas dataframe.

```
from pandas import DataFrame, read_csv
df = read_csv(f,sep='\t')
print df
```

Output:

```
   502  15  \
0  502  24   
1  502   3   
2  502  66   
3  502  28   
4  502  27   

  {\"p\":\"car\",\"rooms\":1,\"floors\":2\"sf\":2000,\"br\":2,\"m\":0}  
0  {\"p\":\"car\",\"rooms\":2,\"floors\":3,\"sf\"...                    
1  {\"p\":\"car\",\"rooms\":9,\"floors\":3,\"sf\"...                    
2  {\"p\":\"bik\",\"rooms\":9,\"floors\":2,\"sf\"...                    
3  {\"p\":\"bik\",\"rooms\":5,\"floors\":1,\"sf\"...                    
4  {\"p\":\"foo\",\"rooms\":5,\"floors\":3,\"sf\"...                    

[5 rows x 3 columns]
```

So, how do I either read this in a better way or convert the string column that is a json into a regular set of columns for 'car', 'rooms', 'floors', 'sf', 'br', 'm'?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: This is not the fundamental cause of your issue but in the first line part of the json looks like this: `"floors\":2\"sf\":2000`. So it's missing a comma after the 2. Is that a typo or does your file have those irregularities?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to take a look at implementing your own converter / parser for `pandas.read_csv`, something like:

```
def JsonParser(input):
  import json
  return json.loads(input)
```

You'd then use this custom converter like this:

```
df = pandas.read_csv(filepath, names=('field1', 'field2', 'field3') converters={'field3':JsonParser})
```

A `df.dtypes` will show that field3 is an `object`.

If at this point you'd like to convert the json data to dataframe fields, you can do this:

```
df.join(df['field3'].apply(pd.Series))
```

This gives me the following results:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but this is splitting things up into the wrong columns and isn't parsing the data correctly.  It looks like this makes it want to parse every field as a separate json.  Thanks for pointing out the converters option, though as this is likely along the right vain.

Comment: Corrected a typo and updated with screenshot showing my results

Comment: Since you've got to do the `apply` anyway, I think it is cleaner to move the `json.loads` and column creation all into the apply (don't use the `converters` for `read_csv`): `df['field3'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(json.loads(x)))`